# Is there a physical reason (like thermal conductivity) why refrigerators are made of steel instead of aluminum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, energy

I have read this question:

> Magnets stick to fridges because fridges are made of steel and steel is ferromagnetic.

[Why are fridge doors magnetic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480822/why-are-fridge-doors-magnetic)

If I look into cost effectiveness, I find contradictory information about the price of aluminum vs steel (I thought naively that steel was more expensive). This is the same with thermal conductivity of steel and aluminum (what I found was that aluminum has better thermal conductivity). Yet, anywhere I look on this site or the internet, I find that refrigerators are made of mostly steel (an to some smaller extent aluminum). I cannot think of any physical reason why it would be more efficient in terms of refrigeration to use steel instead of aluminum.

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thermal-conductivity-metals-d_858.html

The other thing I can think of is weight, where steel is much more heavier then aluminum, so this does not answer the question either.

So there are basically three things coming to mind:

1. price
2. thermal conductivity
3. weight

But none of them explain why refrigerators are made of steel instead of aluminum. Is there any physical reason?

Just to clarify, steel is heavier then aluminum, and in certain cases steel is more expensive, and I am not sure if the thermal conductivity difference explains it. So is there any other physical explanation why?

I edited the question to make it clear that I am asking for a physical reason.

Question:

1. Is there a physical reason (like thermal conductivity) why refrigerators are made of steel instead of aluminum?

Comment: Steel is a _worse_ thermal conductor than aluminum. You want to keep heat _out_. Steel is cheap, easy to form, more than strong enough, easy to weld, ...

Comment: Why was this closed? I am specifically stating, that I am asking for a physical reason.

Comment: Aluminum easily distorts, (think of distorted doors of the fridge) and that must be the reason it is not used. For heat etc constants plastic would be much better, but the fridge would have a small lifetime. (also it can break easily in transport)

Answer (score 3):

Price: Steel and aluminium have a similar price per kg, although the price of aluminium fluctuates more than that of steel. So approximately equal here, but a sligh twin for steel I believe.

Strength: Steel is significantly stronger and harder than aluminium, so you can use thinner panels and they are less likely to  be scuffed, scratched, or dented with normal handling. So steel wins here.

Weight: Steel is stronger, but denser. So for a structural member you generally need less mass of aluminium to withstand the same load. But the difference is relatively small and much of the weigh tof a refrigerator is in the compressor/heat exchanger/shelves/etc. Maybe a small win for aluminium, but not by much.

Manufacturability: Steel is easier to manuifacture into components (because you can use thinner steel sheet it can be bent more sharply). Much easier to weld/spot-weld. Because it is stronger you can use thinner fastening components to cut prices. Steel wins here.

Corrosion: Aluminium corrodes less than plain steel but more than stainless. But for asthetic purposes, aluminium would need painting or coating (see Strength above), whereas steel doesn't always. And for interior use corrosion isn't a significant issue. Slight win for steel.

Thermal conductivity: in practically any domestic fridge, there is a non-metallic insulation layer that provides the barrier to stop heat getting in. So irrelevant here. A dead tie (except you likely will find aluminium in the heat exchanger panel - 'cos that is where good thermal conductivity is relevant.

So overall, manufacturability and surface damage resistance means that steel trumps aluminium for most large domestic whiteware - especially in teh external sheet-metal. Interior components have less of a bias (for example the body of a water-pump is more likely to be aluminium than steel, because it is ligthter, easier to machine, and strong enough (although probably plastic these days). And plastic almost invariably wins out over both Fe and Al in small appliances.

Comment: Thank you so much!